# How to detect whether app is opened using app icon click or opened from notification click?

Tags: android, push-notification

There are 3 cases in Push Notification.

1. Case 1 : App is already running and notification appears.
2. Case 2 : App is closed and notification appears but app is opened by  clicking app icon
3. Case 3 : App is closed and app is opened from notification click

My question is how to detect whether app is opened from case 2 or case 3? If I able to detect than I can save some value in preference and using that value I can differentiate whether I have to open Main Activity or Notification Activity.

If you have better idea to decide which activity should be opened after splash (either Main Activity or Notification Activity) than Kindly tell me.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle("My Notification")
    .setContentText("You have a received notification.")
    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
           R.drawable.ic_launcher))
    .build();
    notification.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.number = notificationCount++;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("pushClicked", true);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    System.out.println("title="+title+"message="+message);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
    int SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED = 1;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED, notification);
```

In the Target(Splash) activity

```
boolean pushClicked = false;
if(getIntent()!=null){
     pushClicked  = getIntent().getStringExtra("pushClicked");
    System.out.println("pushClicked="+pushClicked); 
    }
System.out.println(pushClicked );
```

Always getting false

Comment: attach a flag to your notification and check the flag at `onCreate`

Comment: I have tried but didn't received at onCreate in Splash Activity

Comment: Your splash activity may be already running in background. Check the flag in onResume

Comment: post what you tried..

Comment: the person who have minus -1 me, can have better question or solution ????

Answer (score 4):

Add an extra boolean value along with the intent created to open up application activity inside notification receiver.
For example :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null)
        return;
    Intent splashIntent = new Intent(context, TargetActivity.class);
            splashIntent.putExtra("pushClicked", true);
    context.startActivity(splashIntent);
}
```

Check for this boolean value inside the TargetActivity to distinguish between push click and app icon click.

Comment: how will you get  pushClicked in Splash Activity if TargetActivity is NotificationsActivity.class

Comment: Intent starting SplashActivity does not contain pushClicked boolean. So set a default value to be false while fetching the value.

Comment: I did this but even not getting any value from intent

Comment: Inside your NotificationsActivity or SplashActivity?

Comment: SplashActivity, I have changed the senario, 1st trying to open direclty Notification Activity, but now I will check this on Splash

Comment: In your Splashactivity, you won't get the pushclicked extra. Thus you can distinguish between the two activities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99686/discussion-between-bhola-nath-mahto-and-febi-mathew).